# Scale <SVG> width to height (100% of parent)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm attempting to create a webpage template with Bootstrap 5.0 fluid containers (a header and a container that adjust so that vertical scroll is never required. Inside of this container, I want to render a D3 map within a svg that will dynamically scale to 100% of its parent container's height (whatever its parent container's height is currently), and adjust its width accordingly to preserve aspect ratio.

I found some styling to get my container to always scale to remaining viewport height without necessitating vertical scroll, included below, but I can't figure out how to instantiate my svg to take up only this vertical space, scale horizontally and resize.

```js
let path = d3.geoPath()

let svg = d3.select("#map-svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")

d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-albers-10m.json").then(
  function(us) {

    svg.selectAll("path.county")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .join("path")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d["id"]
      })
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("fill", "#E7E7E8")
      .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.3")
      .attr("d", path)
  }
)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#header-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#map-div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#map-svg {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper-div">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header-div">
      HEADER TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="map-div">
      <svg id="map-svg"></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It is possible that svg element is interpreted as inline by default. Add "display: block; width: auto; height: 100%;" for style attribute to #map-svg either using setAttribute or d3's ".attr" or within your CSS file and see if that works. Since width will be auto, you can set preserveAspectRatio to "none".

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin thanks tried this, unfortunately does not seem to help (still overflowing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to adjust the spaces in a container when you set its `box-sizing` property to `border-box` first to make sure that your containers maintain the same height and width when you adjust their `margin` and `padding`. To make it scale horizontally, just add `width: 100%;` to your `#map-svg`. To make it stay on 100 viewport without the overflow, what I did was to set the `#wrapper-div` to have a `height` of `100vh`, made the `header` absolute and set the `height` of `#map-svg` the same with `#wrapper-div`'s height, added some padding as well to avoid overlapping of header and the map. Check the snippet below for your reference:

```js
let path = d3.geoPath()

let svg = d3.select("#map-svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")

d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-albers-10m.json").then(
  function(us) {

    svg.selectAll("path.county")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .join("path")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d["id"]
      })
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("fill", "#E7E7E8")
      .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.3")
      .attr("d", path)
  }
)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper-div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#header-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#map-svg {
  background-color: lightpink;
  padding: 1.5rem 0 .5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper-div">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header-div">
      HEADER TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="map-div">
      <svg id="map-svg"></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This works well enough but do you know if there's a way to overcome the padding adjustment? Just in case you wanted to change the sibling prior to the map div (e.g. if I change font-size in the header-div it will then overlap)?

Comment: *I realize also that this pins the map svg height to the viewport, which I also didn't intend — I suppose I would just apply those styles to the map div in order to overcome this.

Comment: If the font-change is increased drastically, then yes it will overlap. Another way you could do this is by giving the `header` a specific height (e.g. `height: 5vh;`) and give the remaining `95vh` to your `#map-svg`. But then again, there're cons to this too.

Comment: You can specify the map's height if you really want to by just giving it a static value (e.g. `height: 600px;` and it would stay that way no matter how you resize your viewport.