# SVG aspect ratio is preserved when width is greater than height despite of the preventive setting

Tags: html, svg, resize

I want the blue line to always connect top left and bottom right corners without overflow and scroll bar being displayed. Currently it only happens for when the width is less than height (more or less), otherwise it increases the height thus resulting in a screen overflow and scrollbar being displayed. No `preserveAspectRatio` option seems to give it out of the box. I'm looking for a markup only solution ideally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <div
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-rows: min-content auto; grid-template-columns: auto;">
        <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <p style="margin: 5px;">Header</p>
        </div>
        <div style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1; display: grid;">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <polyline points="0,0 1000,1000" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: Working sample following the brilliant explanation from Dave:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <div
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(0, 1fr); grid-template-columns: auto;">
        <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <p style="margin: 5px;">Header</p>
        </div>
        <div style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1; display: grid;">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <polyline points="0,0 1000,1000" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want the svg to change aspect ratio such that the diagonal line is always wholly in view.

Your svg is structured correctly to do this with `preserveAspectRatio="none"` on an image drawn with user units for the line and viewbox matching.

The reason your svg is extending beyond the page height is because the container div extends beyond the page height.

I've added a class to the parent div containing the svg and styled it to have height of `100vh` ( minus a nominal pixel value to ensure scroll bars don't show). I also gave the div a border so you can see it now occupies the viewable screen and the SVG remders the line from top left to bottom right corners.

On a resizable page, the div will resize and the svg will change aspect ratio to always occupy it.

```css
.svgFrame {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

```html
        <div class="svgFrame" style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1; display: grid;">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <polyline points="0,0 1000,1000" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px" />
            </svg>
        </div>
```

The key is to constrain the parent div such that it remains entirely in view on the page; without constraint the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` has no effect as the there is no reason to change the aspect ratio.

In this example based on a grid layout, styling the grid containing the parent div using `minmax(0, 1fr)` had the desired effect.

Comment: Upvoted, but - the container div never overflows, the overflow is caused by svg poliline, so the best I can explain it is SVG doesn't honor 100% height setting. If I set it manually it works except that I can't do it in real life. I saw that people use that viewport height units (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689439/scale-svg-width-to-height-100-of-parent)- but my setup is more complex than the sample so I can't use any calculated values, leaving aside the elegance aspect of it.

Comment: I've had another look and, if I change the div height to 100%, the svg stretches the div to go offscreen, rather than overflows it. I'm convinced the key keeping the entire svg in view is to constain the container div to the visible screen. Instead of using calc to remove a few pixels and prevent the scroll bars, setting a smaller vh value will achieve the same effect e.g. 90vh or there abouts.

Comment: why would the svg overflow its parent never mind going offscreen? I effectively instructed the svg to rasterize its contents which it failed to do. it could be understood if it'd struggle to fit the contents etc. but in my examples no boundaries were pushed.

Comment: The svg is sized to 100% height and width of the parent element, without constraining the parent div, the svg will naturally render, as specified, with a height equal to its width as that is what the drawing aspect ratio is. `preserveAspectRatio="none"` allows the aspect ratio to change if the parent container can't accommodate the height needed to preserve the ratio for whatever the 100% width is but will not do anything if the parent can accommodate it as specified.

Comment: Makes sense. Believe it or not but I've got it working by setting the second grid row to use minmax(0, 1fr) - purely thanks to the explanation given by you. The answer is yours really.

Comment: Grid often has some excellent non-obvious talents! well done.

Comment: would you mind publishing it as an answer as it will can help to others - it's really yours like I said.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit, let me know if I should modify it (or feel free to edit if the edit link shows for you).